# Collectd - Users:plugin How to Use

Tags: linux, monitoring, graphite, collectd

Unfortunately there is no documentation/man pages in how to use the plugin. Here's the link: [https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Users](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin%3aUsers)

I see that Sebastian Harl was the author of the plugin. I have posted an issue to the github for collectd with the request of a man page for this plugin.

Any idea on how to use this plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Users plugin doesn't need any configuration. To use it all you need is `LoadPlugin "users"`.

From the answer to the resolved [Github Issue](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/606):

> This plugin has no option, this is why the collectd.conf manpage
>   doesn't document it. It's basically just a matter of adding LoadPlugin
>   users to your config and you're done.